# Best way to tally/find quantity all elements in an object with a given ID?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop, object

The concept is simple, I have two datasets. One is "classes" and one is "attendees". Each Class has a unique ID and some other stuff, like so (the actual data sets are much bigger):

```
[{class_id: 9, class_cap: 50, class_name: 'Science'},{class_id: 10, class_cap: 30, class_name: 'French'}]
```

Attendees is similar, where class_id represents the class they are attending:

```
[{attendee_id: 55, class_id: 9, attendee_name: 'Jack'},{attendee_id: 56, class_id: 10, attendee_name: 'Jill'}]
```

What I need to do is be able to find out the quantity of students that will be attending each class. I have tried to do it using a for loop and if statement, in an attempt to create a new array for every class which stores the attendee ID of every student attending it (then I can just use length to get quantity of students), but it's not working properly and I can't wrap my head around the correct implementation. The idea is to iterate through every class, and then for every class, iterate through all the attendees to find ones with the same class_id, and then add it to the attendeeArray.

```
for (let i = 0; i < classes.length; i++){
      let classID = classes[i].class_id;
      let attendeeArray = [];
          for (let d = 0; d < attendees.length; d++){
             if(attendees[i].class_id == classID){                        
             attendeeArray[i] = attendees[i].attendee_id;
          }
console.log(`Attendance number for class ID ${classID} is ${attendeeArray.length}`)
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Any method is fine. Thanks

Comment: Group the "Attendees" by `class_id`. If you also need the classes with no attendees, then filter `classes` with the result of the grouping -> _"javascript array of objects group by"_

Comment: Just curious, are your classes ordered in the array according to id with no missing id's because that could make things much easier

Comment: this is probably just a typo but do you mean `attendees[d]` as opposed to `attendees[i]` and also you should use `attendeeArray.push(attendees[d].attendee_id)` instead of `attendeeArray[i] = attendees[i].attendee_id;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const classes = [{class_id: 9, class_cap: 50, class_name: 'Science'},{class_id: 10, class_cap: 30, class_name: 'French'}]

const students = [{attendee_id: 55, class_id: 9, attendee_name: 'Jack'},{attendee_id: 56, class_id: 10, attendee_name: 'Jill'}]


const classOccupancy = classes.map(oneClass => ({
  class_id:oneClass.class_id,
  number_attendees: students.filter(student => student.class_id === oneClass.class_id).length
}))


console.log(
  `Attendance number for class ID ${classOccupancy[0].class_id} is ${classOccupancy[0].number_attendees}`
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit to late:

```js
let classes = [{ class_id: 9, class_cap: 50, class_name: 'Science' }, { class_id: 10, class_cap: 30, class_name: 'French' }];
let attendees = [{ attendee_id: 55, class_id: 9, attendee_name: 'Jack' }, { attendee_id: 56, class_id: 10, attendee_name: 'Jill' }];

let attClassesCount = classes.map(c => {
    let attCount = attendees.filter(a => a.class_id === c.class_id).length;
    return { class_id: c.class_id, attendees_count: attCount }
})

console.log(attClassesCount);
```